# Unable to send JSON response from grails controller to jQuery datatable

Tags: json, grails, datatables

I have been trying to send JSON response from grails controller to display in jQuery datatable(v 1.9) but I'm getting null response.

Here is my controller:-

```
def breakHierarchy = 
{
    logger.info("breakHierarchy begins here");
    userObject = session.myBeanU;
    userLoggedIn = userStatus.checkUserLoggedIn(userObject);

    ArrayList<HierarchyBreakBean> mappingList;
    JsonObject jsonResponse;

    if(userLoggedIn) {
        def hierarchyBreakInstance = new HierarchyBreak(params);                        
        String[] divisionList = params.searsDivNumber;
        String[] lineList = params.searsLineNumber;
        String[] sublineList = params.searsSubLineNumber;
        String[] classList = params.searsClass;

        try {
            mappingList = hierarchyBreakService.searchHierarchy(divisionList, lineList, sublineList, classList);
            jsonResponse = hierarchyBreakService.loadData(request, response, mappingList);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            logger.info("Exception in breakHierarchy: ");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            hierarchyBreakInstance.errors.reject(message(code: ex.toString()));
            render(view: "hierarchyBreak", model: [hierarchyBreakInstance: hierarchyBreakInstance]);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        redirect(action: loginError);
    }       

    return;
}
```

This the method loadData() in the Service:-

```
try {
        JsonObject jsonResponse = new JsonObject();
        jsonResponse.addProperty("sEcho", sEcho);
        jsonResponse.addProperty("iTotalRecords", iTotalRecords);
        jsonResponse.addProperty("iTotalDisplayRecords", iTotalDisplayRecords);

        Iterator<HierarchyBreakBean> it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            JsonArray row = new JsonArray();
            record = it.next();
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive("<input type='checkbox' class='singleSelect' id='item' name='item' value='' />"));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getSearsCategoryNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getSearsBusNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getSearsDivNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getSearsLineNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getSearsSublineNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getSearsClassNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getKmartDivNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getKmartDeptNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getKmartCatGroupNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getKmartCatgNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getKmartSubCatgNumber()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getOrderSystem()));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(record.getSearskmartOrderSystemCode()));
            data.add(row);
        }

        jsonResponse.add("aaData", data);
        response.setContentType("application/Json");
        response.getWriter().print(jsonResponse);
        return jsonResponse;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the JS I'm using:-

```
var myTable = null;

$("#searchButton").click(function(){    
    var url = appcontextPath + "/login/breakHierarchy";

    $("#row_header").show();
    myTable = $("#mappingTable").dataTable({"bServerSide": true,
                                            "bProcessing": true,
                                            "sAjaxSource": url,
                                            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                                            "bJQueryUI": true, 
                                            "bDestroy": true,
                                            "aaSorting": [[4,'asc']],
                                            "bFilter": false,                                   
              "aoColumnDefs": [{"sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [1,2,3,4,5], "sClass": "center"}, 
                                                             {"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0]}]
    });
});
```

The datatable is displayed empty with the "Processing" bar.
Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: there should be some errors in JS-console

Comment: I did not see `render jsonResponse` in your controller;

Comment: @injecteer My JS console is clean

Comment: @codehx Do I neeed to use render to send jsonResponse to the JS? Is it not sent directly by writing to the output stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your action does nothing with the JSON object you create. Either use `render data` or return the json object as the action's return value:

```
 mappingList = hierarchyBreakService.searchHierarchy(divisionList, lineList, sublineList, classList);
 jsonResponse = hierarchyBreakService.loadData(request, response, mappingList);
 render jsonResponse
```

Also your service method looks to java-ish. Using a JSON Builder would reduce a complexity by 50%

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Grails. I wrote the same code in Java and sent the response through Spring controller and it worked. However I'm unable to send the response using Grails.

Comment: I used render jsonResponse and it gave me the following JS error:- Datatables warning: JSON data from the server could not be parsed. This is caused by JSON formatting error. I also used render jsonResponse as JSON but it then threw the error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject

Could you please help me on this!

Comment: debug your JS code to see how exactly the `response` look like.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. My JSON was misconstructed due to some other error. I resolved it now.